# How read made efficient in Cassandra using JanusGraph on OLAP jobs?

Tags: janusgraph

I am new to JanusGraph and had some hand-on on Cassandra. I know, Cassandra is not that good at querying with full scan queries and good at only point queries as it maintains index of the primary key. The question is how the queries are optimized when running OLAP jobs in Spark using JanusGraph??

Comment: You may want to check https://www.experoinc.com/expero-resources/janusgraph-community-meetup Sorry for the registration barrier, I will address that elsewhere.

Comment: I believe this is the resource you are mentioning to https://youtu.be/cI78vJAIkVI.. @HadoopMarc